# Display relevant contents if radio button is clicked using knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have four radio buttons and I want to display relevant contents for each of them if they are clicked. I am using knockout.js for data binding.

Is there a better way to write the if statement block?

```html
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: print_size_radio" name="print-size" value="Standard" />Standard (Letter)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2" data-bind="visible:print_size_standard">
    <label>No. of Copies
      <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_standard_q, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: print_size_radio" name="print-size" value="13 x 19" />13" x 19"</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2" data-bind="visible:print_size_13_19">
    <label>No. of Copies
      <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_13_19_q, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
<li></li>
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: print_size_radio" name="print-size" value="Contact Sheet">Contact Sheet</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2" data-bind="visible:print_size_contact">
    <label>No. of Images/Page
      <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_contact_q, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
    </label>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: print_size_radio" name="print-size" value="Custom Size" />Custom Size</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9" data-bind="visible:print_size_custom">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <label>Width
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_custom_w, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-offset-1">
        <label>Height
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_custom_h, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-offset-1">
        <label>Pixels/Inches
          <select data-bind="options: print_size_custom_units, value: print_size_custom_sel"></select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 col-offset-1">
        <label>No. of Copies
          <input type="text" data-bind="value:print_size_custom_q, valueUpdate:'keyup'" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

```
self.print_size_radio.subscribe(function(p) {
  if (p == 'Standard') {
    self.print_size_standard(true);
    self.print_size_13_19(false);
    self.print_size_contact(false);
    self.print_size_custom(false);
  } else if (p == '13 x 19') {
    self.print_size_standard(false);
    self.print_size_13_19(true);
    self.print_size_contact(false);
    self.print_size_custom(false);
  } else if (p == 'Contact Sheet') {
    self.print_size_standard(false);
    self.print_size_13_19(false);
    self.print_size_contact(true);
    self.print_size_custom(false);
  } else if (p == 'Custom Size') {
    self.print_size_standard(false);
    self.print_size_13_19(false);
    self.print_size_contact(false);
    self.print_size_custom(true);
  } else {
    self.print_size_standard(false);
    self.print_size_13_19(false);
    self.print_size_contact(false);
    self.print_size_custom(false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much better it is, but some would say it could look nicer to intialize everything to false, then only change when true.  Like so:

```
self.print_size_radio.subscribe(function(p) {

   self.print_size_standard(false);
   self.print_size_13_19(false);
   self.print_size_contact(false);
   self.print_size_custom(false);

   if (p == 'Standard') {
      self.print_size_standard(true);
   } 
   else if (p == '13 x 19') {
      self.print_size_13_19(true);
   } 
   else if (p == 'Contact Sheet') {
      self.print_size_contact(true);
   } 
   else if (p == 'Custom Size') {
      self.print_size_custom(true);
   }
});
```